# How to setup NDK on circleci for android app or lib project?

Tags: android, android-ndk, circleci

I have an Android lib project that has some C code that it depends on. In order for it to compile it needs to run `compileNdk...` task.

Setting up the NDK locally is pretty straightforward. However, getting it to work with circleci is not so straightforward. The circleci docs have a good amount of info on how to install the android SDK properly but there is nothing on how to properly install NDK on circleci.

What is the best way to install the Android NDK on circleci so it can successfully build/compile with my continuous integration setup?

Answer (score 4):

CircleCI actually installs the NDK. It can be referenced by using the $ANDROID_NDK environment variable.

They explain this at the end of the dependencies section here https://circleci.com/docs/android

Comment: When this post was written they didn't do that.

Comment: I have referenced  $ANDROID_NDK environment variable, but still getting the error message as NDK not configured.

Comment: @somia this is only working on Ubuntu 12 container at the time of writing. If you're using 14, it looks like they forgot to add the NDK :(

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking now, at the time of writing, CircleCI still does not bundle the NDK in the 14.04 environment.

However, you can add it manually and cache it

```
dependencies:
  cache_directories:
    - ~/android-ndk-r11c
  pre:
    - if [[ ! -e ~/android-ndk-r11c ]]; then wget http://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r11c-linux-x86_64.zip && unzip -d ~ android-ndk-r11c-linux-x86_64.zip; fi
```

And add the environment vars manually:

```
machine:
  environment:
    ANDROID_NDK: $HOME/android-ndk-r11c
    ANDROID_NDK_HOME: $ANDROID_NDK
    PATH: $PATH:$ANDROID_NDK
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well. However, it's possible to extract it to the home directory as well to avoid having to specify `YOUR_BUILD_FOLDER` in the configuration. Use `~/android/ndk-r11c/` and `! -e ~/android-ndk-r11c` and `unzip -d ~ android-ndk-r11c-linux-x86_64.zip` will cache/check/extract the NDK folder to the home directory instead.

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE: circleci now installs NDK for you.

The best solution I have found so far is to install the NDK via wget and run the bin file. It also requires setting up an environment variable for ANDROID_NDK_HOME.

Here is a sample of what I have successfully running on circleci.

`circle.yml`
  machine:
    environment:
      ANDROID_HOME: /home/ubuntu/android
      ANDROID_NDK_HOME: /home/ubuntu/android/android-ndk

dependencies:
    cache_directories:
      - ~/.android
      - ~/android
    override:
      - ./install-dependencies.sh

`install-dependencies.sh`
  if [ ! -e $DEPS ]; then
      ... &&
      wget http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r10d-linux-x86_64.bin -O $ANDROID_HOME/android-install-ndk.bin &&
      chmod a+x $ANDROID_HOME/android-install-ndk.bin &&
      cd $ANDROID_HOME && $ANDROID_HOME/android-install-ndk.bin &&
      mv $ANDROID_HOME/android-ndk* $ANDROID_HOME/android-ndk
      touch $DEPS
    fi

Comment: I have tried this solution.. But it is still failing for me. Could you please help me to figure out the issue?